# setTimeOut in while loop

Tags: javascript, while-loop, settimeout

My objective is to create a simon game, and I am currently trying to change the color of each div as follows:

I am storing div classes randomly from 0 to 3; each iteration of the game adds a number to the array

```
var save =[];
```

I want to highlight the div purple at one second, at two seconds, bring it back to the assigned css color and repeat this until it iterates through all the save array class numbers.

at first i tried to do this:

```
setTimeout(function(){ $("."+save[0]).css("background-color", "purple"); },1000)

setTimeout(function(){ $("."+save[0]).css("background-color", ""); },2000)

setTimeout(function(){ $("."+save[1]).css("background-color", "purple"); },3000)

setTimeout(function(){ $("."+save[1]).css("background-color", ""); },4000)
```

and so on and so forth, as i add more iterations to the simon game.

I want to do this instead :

```
 var i = 0;
  function hello() {
      $("." + save[i]).css("background-color", "purple");
  }

  function goodbye() {
      $("." + save[i]).css("background-color", "");
  }

  var one = 1000;
  var two = 2000;


  while (i < save.length) {
      setTimeout(hello(), one);
      setTimeout(goodbye(), two);

      i++;

      one += 2000;
      two += 2000
  }
```

i went through several stack overflow questions, found similar ones, but nothing that helped. I can imagine there's youtube videos on creating this game, but I would like to figure out as much as I could on my own, it's just this one thing that has me scratching my head.

Comment: You cannot pass a function with parameters to setTimeout. Wrap it into an anonymous function.

Comment: please review an answer and let me know is it working for your or not?

Comment: I eliminated the parameters. Also I attempted to wrap it into a function. Still no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the answer by using recursion, a for loop and set interval. The loopIt function changes the color to purple every two seconds and the loopIt2 function changes the color back to its css-assigned color every two seconds but starting one second after function loopIt. The loop stops the recursion after it iterates through the length of the array.

```
var save = [".1", ".0", ".3", ".2", ".1"];   

var i = 0;

function loopIt(i) {

setTimeout(function(){ 

  $("."+save[i]).css("background-color", "purple");

  if(i < save.length - 1)  loopIt(i+1)}, 2000);
}

function loopIt2(i) {
  setTimeout(function(){

setTimeout(function(){ $("."+save[i]).css("background-color", ""); },1000)

  if(i < save.length - 1)  loopIt2(i+1)}, 2000);
}
```

This is the final project result https://codepen.io/salamancajr/pen/ZrKKaa?editors=0010

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code and requirement understanding I tried to solve your issue.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var changeColor = setInterval(function() {
    var hasClassPurple = $(".wrapper").hasClass("purple");
    if (true === hasClassPurple) {      $(".wrapper").removeClass("purple").addClass("white");
    } else {      $(".wrapper").removeClass("white").addClass("purple");
    }
  }, 1000);
  // Don't forget to add clearInterval when you want to terminate setInterval();
  //clearInterval(changeColor);
});
```

```css
.purple {
  background-color: purple;
}

.white {
  background-color: white;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var changeColor = setInterval(function() {
    var hasClassPurple;
    $(".div-wrapper").each(function(index) {
      hasClassPurple = $(this).hasClass("purple");
      if (true === hasClassPurple) { $(this).removeClass("purple").addClass("white");
      } else {
       $(this).removeClass("white");  $(this).removeClass("white").addClass("purple");
      }
    });
  }, 1000);
  // Don't forget to add clearInterval when you want to terminate setInterval();
  //clearInterval(changeColor);
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
}

.purple {
  background-color: purple;
}

.white {
  background-color: white;
}

.div-wrapper {
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: realtive;
  ;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class="div-wrapper purple">
  </div>
  <div class="div-wrapper white">
  </div>
  <div class="div-wrapper purple">
  </div>
  <div class="div-wrapper white">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that is one part of what I want to do. But what I really want is to have four divs not one and to pass the time event through a loop to iterate through an array that is made up of the wrapper class of each div.

Comment: Ok then after 2 hours I shall in front of computer, I shall give you an answer.

Comment: can you explain me particular requirement in simple Lehman style.

Comment: @GeorgeSalamanca I have update code with multiple box, please see my answer, as your question code what I understand and trying to give an answer.